# Why does JCarousel fail to appear?

Tags: jquery, html, jcarousel

I have followed the instructions here:

[jCarousel link](http://sorgalla.com/jcarousel/docs/reference/installation.html)

And it does not appear (only the CSS is working, it appears the actual function is not).

This is my HTML Head:

```
<head>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/style.css"/>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/scripts.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.jcarousel.min.js"></script>

<title>Sites</title>
<script>
$(function() {
    $('.jcarousel').jcarousel({
        // Configuration goes here
    });
});    
</script>

</head>
```

This is the actual part where I wanted the Carousel:

```
    <div class="jcarousel">
        <ul>
            <li><img src="Images/prio_site2.png" width="600" height="400" alt=""></li>
            <li><img src="Images/prio_site_mouseover.PNG" width="600" height="400" alt=""></li>
        </ul>
    </div>
```

Also, the CSS considered Necessary is in the CSS file. Any idea what's going on? The carousel is completely not appearing.

Comment: When you say "not completely appearing"... is it appearing in part?

Comment: can you create a jsFiddle to illustrate your problem?

Comment: @Bobby5193 that would be hard to do with the question needing JCarousel. As far as I know, there's no hosted version of the plugin...

Comment: ok, then Maybe it's a syntax mistake, I'll post an answer here

Comment: @Bobby5193 I don't know how to use JFiddle with an external Java plugin like JCarousel I'm afraid. I believe the code I have in the original post should be enough? It is as though it is a blank document with just a carousel.

Comment: @Askanison4 No. Only the images are appearing resised (due to the required CSS, which can be seen here: http://sorgalla.com/jcarousel/docs/reference/installation.html#style-the-carousel

Comment: @k4kuz0 so the images are appearing all at the same time? Are you sure the jcarousel library is loading?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$(document).ready(function() {
        $('.jcarousel').jcarousel();
    });
```

Have you tried calling the function without the brackets ?

I've also made a working fiddle here : http://jsfiddle.net/bobby5193/2J4yk/

The brackets might not be a problem, but the css properties should be checked for the next/prev buttons. Also you can check with Dev tools in chrome and see if you have missing css properties or js errors.

Comment: The brackets are for a configuration object... I don't think an empty object would cause problems

Comment: @Askanison4 - It was an assumption, I know what the brackets are for, but I've created a working fiddle and updated my answer. It's probably some missing css properties.

Comment: @Bobby5913 I did not know you could add external JS files to a fiddle. +1 for teaching me something! :D

Comment: Thank you. I managed to see what I was doing wrong with your fiddle. I didn't include the function correctly inside my JQuery.